# How to align picture perfectly?

Tags: html, css

How do I align my pictures perfectly I've got them next to each other but ones slightly lower than the other and I can't get them on the same line. Is there anyway apart from position relative that I can use?

Here is my code:

```
#newRelises{
  width:650px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-top:5px;
}

#newRelises img{
  width:170px;
  height:170px;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an online sample of it? Can you make a fiddle for it?

Comment: Your `display: inline` negates your `float: left` (the latter is an implicit `display: block`).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cKePX/1/ there you go (the divs in my example arent really very necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Get rid of `float:left` from `#newRelises` and `#newRelises img`
2. change `display:inline` to `display:inline-block`
3. If you want your images centered, add `text-align:center` to `#newRelises`

Comment: This doesn't work it just stays in the same place but moves my side menu to the bottom of the page

Comment: Hmm... there must be something else going on then because `display:inline-block` should have done the trick as you can see by the jsFiddle posts in the comments.  Would you mind updating your original post with the HTML you are working with?  If you have other elements on the page that are `floated` then that might be the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on both images.

```
img {display:inline-block;}
```

Update: And I see @adaam already posted a fiddle as a comment, so I am going to copy it down here since it's the same solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/elvista/cKePX/2/

Answer (score 0):

You may add "overflow:hidden;" . SO your final code will be like this:

```
#newRelises{
width:650px;
float:left;
margin:5px 0 0 15px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#newRelises img{
width:170px;
height:170px;
float:left;
display:block;
padding:0;
margin:0 0 15px 15px;
}
```